# Custom Whitelist Pattern Configuration

Tags: camunda

How do you add in a Custom Whitelist pattern for User, Group and Tenant IDs?

Reading the [Camunda Manual](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.10/user-guide/process-engine/identity-service/), the property `groupResourceWhitelistPattern` should be able to be added to the process engine config file.

In the bpm-platform.xml file:

```xml
<properties>
  <property name="history">full</property>
  <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate">true</property>
  <property name="authorizationEnabled">true</property>
  <property name="jobExecutorDeploymentAware">true</property>
  <property name="historyCleanupBatchWindowStartTime">00:01</property>

  <property name="groupResourceWhitelistPattern" value="[a-zA-Z0-9-]+" />
</properties>
```

the element `groupResourceWhitelistPattern` causes Tomcat & the BPM engine not to start.

Note that the new property has an attribute so this may cause the parsing to fail but this is directly from the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Correct approach for doing so:
place the  regular expression in between property tag...

```xml
<properties>
  <property name="history">full</property>
  <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate">true</property>
  <property name="authorizationEnabled">true</property>
  <property name="jobExecutorDeploymentAware">true</property>
  <property name="historyCleanupBatchWindowStartTime">00:01</property>
  <property name="generalResourceWhitelistPattern">.+</property>
</properties>
```